# How to fix System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException in bot composer?

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I build a bot using bot composer. After deployment, I able to see some exceptions in Application insights regarding **System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException** , These are the Outer message :

- No adapter registered and enabled for route jsonws.
- No adapter registered and enabled for route index.html.
- No adapter registered and enabled for route swagger.json.
- No adapter registered and enabled for route swagger.yaml.
- No adapter registered and enabled for route swagger-resources.
- No adapter registered and enabled for route swagger_doc.json.

How to fix this exception ?

New to Azure bot.. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!